# Chip Operation Mode selection in binary

Tags: usb-c, binary, sata

For my project, I would like to design my own SATA->USB-C adaptor.

For this, I'm using the Odroid schematic ([here](https://dn.odroid.com/Accessory/USB3.0%20to%20SATA%20BRIDGE%20PLUS_REV0.1_20170517.pdf)), and also the schematics of Cubieboard ([here](http://esys.ir/images/img_Item/1314/Files/CubieBoard7_S700_20170612.pdf)).

My question is about the [JMS539 datasheet](http://files.pine64.org/doc/rock64/PDS-16002%20JMS578%20Datasheet%20(Rev.%201.01).pdf), more precisely the pin 46. Here is the JMicron explanation :

[image]

On the Odroid schematics, `MODE_1` is `VCC` (5 V), and on the Cubieboard `MODE_1` is `VCC0` (3.3 V).

So, I'm wondering, what is `2'b01`? `VCC` or `VCCO`? I know that `2'b01` is binary, but it's incomprehensible for me.

Comment: I did not see that before either, but I would interpret it as (two digits binary: 01)

Comment: @StefanWyss thanks. So, VCC or VCCO are both OK according to you ?

Comment: It seems to be unclear. But as all GPIOs have a maximum rating of 3.6V, I would go with VCCO

Comment: Absolute Maximum Ratings (page 16) says Digital I/O input voltage max 3.6V, so putting 5V on MODE[0] pin could damage the JMS578. The only pin that is designed to tolerate 5V (5.5V) is the USB VBUS power supply input.